# VueJs - Call an event when scrollbar of inner div reach its bottom position of page

Tags: vue.js

Currently i am working in a project which is already developed in v-DataTable of vuejs which is all new to me. In this project, i need to call an event when the scrollbar reach its bottom.

Any API can also be used.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If project is built with Vuetify (guessing because you've mentioned v-data-table) - take a look at https://vuetifyjs.com/en/directives/intersect/

Otherwise you can check out [Interesection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) or third party libraries like [Tornis](https://tornis.robbowen.digital/)